# Reading and output .pcap file in Java

Tags: java, network-programming, pcap, fileinputstream, tcpdump

Objective: To input a .pcap file and output each byte (in binary form) on a new line.
Current code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class display {
    private static FileInputStream input;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("theDump.pcap");
            int content = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            while ((content = input.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.println(counter + ". " + (byte)content);
                counter++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

The .pcap file was made using tcpdump with the -w flag. 
Current output of the code above:
0. -44
1. -61
2. -78
3. -95
4. 2
5. 0
6. 4
7. 0
8. 0
9. 0
... and so on... 
I'm trying to get the output in readable binary, so 255 should be output as 1111 1111
Also, I'm not allowed to use any external library apart from the ones that come with JDK 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for conversion of `int` to binary, but haven't added anything in the code to do that. `Integer` wrapper class contains a [built-in API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) that may help you with that:

```
System.out.println(counter + ". " + Integer.toBinaryString(content));
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there a way to make sure all the output is 8bit binary? Some of the output after making the change you suggested is not in 8bit
Eg: 0 is output as 0 and not 0000 0000

Comment: You can do the following : `String binary= Integer.toBinaryString(256 + content);
 System.out.println(counter + ". " + binary.substring(binary.length() - 8));`

Comment: Thanks that solved it! If you don't mind, can you explain why we add 256 to the int "content".
When learning Computer Science I learnt that a byte was 8 bits and can have max value of 255 and least value of 0
Why does Java put a mysterious negative sign on the byte?

Comment: For understanding this, I would suggest reading through this explanation : https://superuser.com/questions/463571/what-is-the-binary-representation-of-256/463593#463593